# Inline element data not appearing where expected after XSL transform

Tags: xslt

With the following XML

```
<para>Refer to Table 3 and Figure <grphcref refid="apm00-02-02-000018" shownow="0">6</grphcref> 
for the door dimensions and clearances.</para>
```

and this XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="prcitem">
        <xsl:for-each select="para">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./grphcref" />
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="grphcref" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="unlist" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grphcref">
        <xsl:variable name="gotoimg" select="concat('#',@refid)"/>
        <a href="{$gotoimg}" >  
             <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="@refid" /> </a> 
</xsl:template>
```

I get:

```
<p>Refer to Table 3 and Figure 6 for the door dimensions and clearances.
```

6 - apm00-02-02-000018

when I expected:

```
<p>Refer to Table 3 and Figure <a href="#apm00-02-02-000018">6 - apm00-02-02-000018</a>
```

for the door dimensions and clearances.

Can anyone offer guidance as to where I went wrong?

thx

Answer (score 1):

If a `para` element is supposed to be transformed to a `p` element then in my view the "natural" way in XSLT is a template

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

If any other elements need special treatment add a template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="grphcref">
        <xsl:variable name="gotoimg" select="concat('#',@refid)"/>
        <a href="{$gotoimg}" >  
             <xsl:value-of select="." /> - <xsl:value-of select="@refid" /> </a> 
</xsl:template>
```

Text nodes are copied through to the result by the built-in templates.

The input sample doesn't explain why you mix template matching and `for-each` and why or whether you need `xsl:apply-templates` with any particularly selected nodes; as long as the input order should be preserved a simple processing of all child nodes with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` should suffice.

Comment: Martin, Thanks for your reply, I should have qualified my question by saying "new to XSL".  I had written an excessively complicated transformation. Your input solved my problem.